# Tomcat webclassloader fails to find a class

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

In a Tomcat 7 I have a pretty standar jar file on WEB-INF/lib. Inside this jar I have this class called Parser, and next to it (on the same dir) I have another one called AutomaticLocalLoader.   Compilation gives no problem at all. In run time the AutomaticLoader class is found, and when It needs the Parser class, I get a NoClassDefFoundError

The Parser and AutomaticLoader class have been working without this problem for 15 years!! in many diferent vers of java and tomact; and now out of the blue, I am getting this NoClassDefFoundError, only for the Parser class.  I already put a copy on a directory inside the WEB-INF/classes path and still got the same error.  I already created my own ClassLoader to see if I get some error loading the class from the WEB-INF/classes directory by myself, but I can load it without problems.

```
 log.info("Leer " + aFlInstructions[i].getAbsolutePath());

LoaderTest A = new LoaderTest();                 
A.test("com.hds.resolve.model.aguila.AutomaticLocalLoader");
LoaderTest B = new LoaderTest();
B.test("com.hds.resolve.model.aguila.Parser");

             if(!bOverrideInputDir)
                 Psr = new Parser(aFlInstructions[i]);
             else
                 Psr = new Parser(aFlInstructions[i], new String[]  { StrLocalDirectory  } );
```

The LoaderTest class, try to create the Class Object for the given name using Class.forName. If NoClassDefFoundError, then try to load the class using my own classloader and then create the class.
For the AutomaticLoader, it succed at the first try. For the Parser class if fails, then successfully load it with the custom classloader. Of course when the code reach the "new Parser" part, the old webclassloader still fails and throws the NoClassDefFoundError.

Both Parser and AutomaticLocalLoader belong to the same package and are stored on the same jar inside WEB-LIB.

Funny enough, the error does always happen on production... but never in my machine. I do not use customs classloaders except for doing this debug. Also, trying an old version of the software seems to fix the error. No idea why.
I think I can hack a solution messing with the tomcat's webclassloader, but I really would prefer to understand what is going wrong with this code.

Comment: If it has been working for 15 years, what has changed? Did you perhaps upgrade Java to version 9 or later? What do the classes look like?

Comment: In That part of the code? I added the  if(!bOverrideInputDir) like 5 years ago... from time to time the Parser gets updated to support new modules, so it has grow, maybe 2000 lines in these years.  But for this error nothing, I have not touched it in more than 6 months.  We are still in java 8, and have been for a while. The same for the tomcat.    I don't know how to describe how they "look like" They are pretty conventional code. I am not doing anything weird or modern with them.  Maybe the one thing exceptional is that the Parser class has 22 innerclasses.

Comment: What are the `package` declarations in each of the two source files (`Parser.java` and `AutomaticLocalLoader.java`)? Where exactly in the web application can the corresponding `.class` files be found? Are there any inner classes in the `Parser` class?